# saving a document to the internet so it can be shared by other users

Tags: xcode, cocoa, ftp, web, nsurl

I have a working Cocoa app that creates a database file and stores it locally.  What I would like to do is store that file on a remove server so that different users of my app at different locations would be sharing the same file.  My thought was to store the file on a website or ftp server, such as www.mydomain.com/mydatafile.

Forgetting about issues like two users attempting to access the file simultaneously for the moment, can someone point me to an example of how to property construct the URL to be used?

I'm thinking that it should be a fairly simple process with two parts, the first of which is a cocoa NSURL question, and the second which is really more of a w3 issue:

1. Create the URL to the file itself, and
2. Append the username and password require to login to the FTP site.

Any nudges in the right direction would be appreciated!

*** edit ***

I should mention that the file I would like to be shared by multiple users, is basically several custom objects stored as a file with NSKeyedArchiver...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to intgrate your app with some cloud based document storage,sharing,editing service like Google docs/drive.

Until and unless you are going to provide very specific file formats native to your app and are doing something out of ordinary.

Using something like this would save you time, and user wont have to create yet another login-id.

Comment: Good suggestion.  At this point it's mostly just for my use and the use of one other person, but I can see that being a benefit for scaling.  Not being familiar with google docs, the question would be, how would I integrate it in Cocoa?  To this point, I've worked exclusively with paths rather than URL's so I'm just getting up to speed on NSURL.

Comment: Check if any SDK is available or not.